# Can GeoJSON FeatureCollections be used to create PostGIS geometries using ST_GeomFromGeoJSON?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

It's a simple question which I have yet to find a definite answer. On the specs page for `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`, it states:

> ST_GeomFromGeoJSON works only for JSON Geometry fragments. It throws
>   an error if you try to use it on a whole JSON document.

Does this refer to a FeatureCollection?

If it is not possible, is there a standard workaround to store FeatureCollection-esque data as geometries?

Answer (score 5):

ST_GeomFromGeoJSON cannot read FeatureCollection documents, and the error you will see is:

> ERROR:  invalid GeoJson representation

However, PostgreSQL 9.3 has many JSON functions that can help extract the relevant parts to be used by ST_GeomFromGeoJSON. See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/142479/1872) to get some ideas.